Where can I fill an array in Angular?
I am following a course, but I think that is using an old version of angular, the code that should work, does not work in my case, I keep having an empty list (<li>No items</li>).
I use the following parts of code :
app.component.html :
<app-test>[testList]="testset"</app-test>

app.module.ts :
// in declarations added : TestComponent

app.component.ts :
export class AppComponent {
  testset: string[] = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4' ];
  title = 'test in Angular';
}

test.component.html :
<u>
  @for (item of testList; track item ) {
  <li>{{ item }}</li>    
} @empty {
<li>No items</li>
}
</u>

test.component.ts :
//  selector: 'app-test',
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() testList: string[] = []; 
  
// I know here the following is working, but that is not what was expected:
// @Input() testList: string[] =  ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4' ];
}

Is this because this is a change in new angular versions, or am I using a wrong place to fill the array ?
 testset: string[] = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4' ];
(in the export part in app.component.ts)
My goal is to understand how the following code should work :
<app-test>[testList]="testset"</app-test>
(in app.component.html)

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

I was already changing the question, hope it is specific enough now. The problem for me is that there are still a lot of variables in this part.

[testList]="testset" wrong syntax it should be <app-test [testList]="testset"> testlist should be inside the selector i think it should work

testList should be an attribute.
See more. https://angular.dev/guide/components/inputs
app.component.html :
<app-test [testList]="testset"> </app-test>


Thank you very much for the quick answer, I really read 10 or more times over the placement of '>'.
